# Why does 1/len(list) return 0?

Tags: python

lets say I have a list `a` and a variable `b = 1/len(a)` but when I display the value of `b` it gives me 0

Comment: Are you using Python 2? In Python 2 you need to specify float division, try `b = 1./len(a)`

Comment: Because integer 1 divided by any number larger than zero has a fractional part, and you're doing integer division where fractional parts are discarded.

Comment: I'm using python 3

Comment: @ECQuant Are you sure?

Comment: Thank you Ken White

Answer (score 2):

Because of integer divided by integer.

Try `b=1.0/len(a)`

Comment: Thank you that did the trick ;)

Comment: Then you aren't using Python 3.

Comment: Can confirm, only `//` integer division will yield the problem from OP